# Expand height of dropable area in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

How can I expand the height of a dropable area when I drag an acceptable item over it ?
(and also, I'd like to animate the height change)

I have tried the onHover modifier with no luck, as it only reacts when I bring the mouse over the dropable area without draging an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem :

First, I have a view which is the area in which I will drop items. It is a few pixels high and is located "in between" the already existing items.

This view has a State `hovered`. When it is set to true, the view has a highlight halo and a bigger height.

```
struct DropableView: View {
    @State  var hovered:      Bool    = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .stroke(self. hovered ? Color.accentColor : Color.clear,
                    lineWidth: 3.0)
            .frame(height: (hovered ? 20.0 : 5.0) )
            .onDrop(of: [UTI_myOwn_UTI],
                    delegate: DropDelegate(hovered: self.$hovered))
    }
}
```

Then, we need a drop delegate that, when entered/exited by the mouse, will change the state so that the view redraws. Make sure that the state modification is done on the main thread, as it will redraw the UI.

```
struct DropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding    var hovered:          Bool

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self. hovered = true
        }
    }

    func dropExited(info: DropInfo)  {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self. hovered = false
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't find how to animate the change. If somebody wants to elaborate...

Of course, you need to provide the `validateDrop(info:)` and `performDrop(info:)` method for your drop to do something, and start the drag with an .onDrag modifier and a NSItemProvider, but that isn't the topic here.